# Why does SQL Server Mangement Studio not script Indexes by default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, scripting

Recently I realized by default, scripting the database does not including indexes, and I have to change the option every time.

Could anyone please explain the reason? Is there any insight about this default behavior, or just because Microsoft likes to do so?

Comment: You'd have to ask the developers of SSMS, more likely the original developers as most defaults won't be changed unless there is a very specific reason to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by "every time"? Every time you generate scripts, or every time you install Management Studio, or something else? As for why it's the default, you'd have to ask Microsoft, not your peers. I can assure you they choose defaults for reasons other than "they like it," but those reasons are not commonly documented. File a suggestion on [the SQL Server feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) and, who knows, maybe they'll tell you why it's that way and/or why they won't change it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Everytime I do a new Scripting operation (right click database -> Task -> Generate Scripts). The options are not remembered, you have to choose it every time.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Yes I am just asking the reason to understand why it is False by default, I just like to know if anyone knows :)

Comment: Change the option in tools / options / Object Explorer / scripting.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nice to know you can change it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to change the option every time. If you change the selection in Tools > Options > Object Explorer > Scripting, it should persist.

As for why not scripting indexes is the default, I have no idea. Not a great question for your peers; if you really want the background, hit up someone on the SSMS team and buy them a beer - maybe they'll be able to share it. You could also consider submitting a suggestion on [the SQL Server feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) (if one doesn't already exist), and they will possibly tell you why it's the default and/or why they won't be changing it.